# Is it possible in Excel VBA to change the source code of Module in another Module

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel .xlam file that adds a button in the ribbon to do the following:

1. Scan the ActiveSheet for some pre-set parameters
2. Take my source text (a string value, hard coded directly in a VBA Module) and replace designated areas with the parameters retrieved from step 1
3. Generate a file containing the calculated text

I save the source text this way because it can be password protected and I don't need to drag another file around everywhere that the .xlam file goes. The source text is saved in a separate module called "Source" that looks something like this (Thanks VBA for not having Heredocs):

```
'Source Module
Public Function GetSource() As String
    Dim s As String
    s = ""

    s = s & "This is the first line of my source text" & vbCrLf
    s = s & "This is a parameter {par1}" & vbCrLf
    s = s & "This is another line" & vbCrLf

    GetSource = s
End Function
```

The function works fine. My problem is if I want to update the source text, I now have to manually do that in the .xlam file. What I would like to do is build something like a `Sub ImportSource()` in another module that will parse some file, rebuild the "Source" Module programatically, then replace that Module with my calculated source code. What I don't know is if/how to replace the source code of a module with some value in a string variable.

It's like metaprogramming at its very worst and philosophically I'm against doing this down to my very core. Practically, however, I would like to know if and how to do it.

Comment: You can "export" and "import" .bas files programmatically. To do what you are asking, that would have to be the approach. I don't believe it's possible to modify the code in memory. See [this article](http://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/w/microstation__wiki/using-vba-to-programmatically-import-a-vba-projects-components-and-references-cs.aspx)

Comment: @Floris: That should work. If you put it as an answer, I can mark it as correct

Comment: Does not solve your problem, but an alternative to storing constants inside you XLAM code is to store them in cells (preferably Named Cells) on a worksheet inside your XLAM.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams: The problem with that is if someone knows where to look, they can see these values without needing the password for the VBA macros. Even if you password protect a sheet, you can still get access to it's values from another sheet using formulas

Comment: Well all Excel & VBA security is weak and easily cracked apart from encypted workbooks, but you can't get at cells on a sheet inside an XLA unless you know at least the name of the sheet inside the XLA, and you cannot see that without cracking the XLA

Comment: @CharlesWilliams: Fair point :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize now that what you really want to do is store some values in your document in a way that is accessible to your VBA, but that is not readable to a user of the spreadsheet. Following Charles Williams's suggestion to store the value in a named range in a worksheet, and addressing your concern that you don't want the user to have access to the values, you would have to encrypt the string...

The "proper way" to do this is described in [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/84d49593-2d8e-4e7c-af3a-61882af9557d) - but it's quite a bit of work.

A much shorter routine is found [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5676). It just uses simple XOR encryption with a hard coded key - but it should be enough for "most purposes". The key would be "hidden" in your macro, and therefore not accessible to prying eyes (well, not easily).

Now you can use this function, let's call it `encrypt(string)`, to convert your string to a value in the spreadsheet:

```
range("mySecretCell").value = encrypt("The lazy dog jumped over the fox")
```

and when you need to use it, you use

```
Public Function GetSource()
    GetSource = decrypt(Range("mySecretCell").value)
End Function
```

If you use the `XOR` version (second link), `encrypt` and `decrypt` would be the same function...

Does that meet your needs better?

Comment: +1 for this as well. One problem that I would actually encounter with this approach is that a single cell in excel can apparently hold no more than 65536 characters. My source is actually more than 100k characters long. I suppose however that I can programatically split the import into multiple cells. Will try this later this week and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Well you could use one cell per line in your code... Note there was no hint in your original question that you would have quite so much text !! And thanks for the upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

As @brettdj already pointed out with his link to [cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) , you can programmatically change to code of a VBA module using the *VBA Extensibility library*! To use it, select the library in the VBA editor *Tools*->*References*. Note that you need to also change the options in your Trust center and select: *Excel Options*->*Trust Center*->*Trust Center Settings*->*Macro Settings*->*Trust access to the VBA project object model*

Then something like the following code should do the job:

```
Private mCodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

Sub UpdateModule()
    Const cStrModuleName As String = "Source"

    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set VBProj = Workbooks("___YourWorkbook__").VBProject

    'Delete the module
    VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBProj.VBComponents(cStrModuleName)

    'Add module
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    VBComp.Name = cStrModuleName
    Set mCodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    'Add procedure header and start
    InsertLine "Public Function GetSource() As String"
    InsertLine "Dim s As String", 1
    InsertLine ""

    'Add text
    InsertText ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sourcetext") _
        .Range("___YourRange___")

    'Finalize procedure
    InsertLine "GetSource = s", 1
    InsertLine "End Function"

End Sub

Private Sub InsertLine(strLine As String, _
    Optional IndentationLevel As Integer = 0)
    mCodeMod.InsertLines _
        mCodeMod.CountOfLines + 1, _
        Space(IndentationLevel * 4) & strLine
End Sub

Private Sub InsertText(rngSource As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim strCell As String, strText As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Const cLineLength = 60
    For Each rng In rngSource.Cells
        strCell = rng.Value
        For i = 0 To Len(strCell) \ cLineLength
            strText = Mid(strCell, i * cLineLength, cLineLength)
            strText = Replace(strText, """", """""")
            InsertLine "s = s & """ & strText & """", 1
        Next i
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "export" and "import" .bas files programmatically. To do what you are asking, that would have to be the approach. I don't believe it's possible to modify the code in memory. See [this article](http://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/w/microstation__wiki/using-vba-to-programmatically-import-a-vba-projects-components-and-references-cs.aspx)