# Disable running macros from the "View Macro" screen until VBA project password is entered?

Tags: vba, excel

So first, when one clicks on the "View Macro" button, this pops up:

[image: View Macros window]

What I want to know is, is there some code that I can run on workbook open (and then "unrun" on workbook close) that grays out that run button (like the others underneath it are) ONLY until the password is entered in the VBA project (using Alt+F11 to open the editor)?

I don't want the users to be able to run any of these subs manually.

Comment: If you don't want the user to run the macros, how will the macros ever be run?

Comment: The first two on that sheet are called from other macros that are run with buttons on my main worksheet.  The middle two are called when the sheet opens and closes, respectively, and the last two I manually call when I want to edit my main sheet.  The way I am set up, I don't want them to run unless they are being properly called.

Comment: @ilarson007 If you want, I can show you how to create a Userform which will prompt the user to enter a username and password on `Workbook_Open`. So the user basically won't be able to open the sheet without this. Then password protect the VBA project you have and you are good to go.

Comment: @CaptainABC I think that might not be the best case for this.  Basically, I only lock the interface sheet so the user can't accidentally hide or delete something, and then I disable right click options so they can't accidentally delete data.  I probably should give my users more credit than I am; they're pretty computer literate.  I just am using specific cells, so it would be a bad thing if they tried changing formatting and whatnot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the sub so that it needs input, even optional input it will not show in the list either.

```
sub Test(optional a as string)
```

Comment: I want to be able to manually call them from this window after I enter my VBA password as opposed to having to search through all my code to find them.  I just don't want the user to be able to run them without the password input.

Comment: However, it would be a good solution if I had different wants/needs from my code.

Comment: Couldn't you use this suggestion and then build a simple userform to act in the same way that the Macros button in the ribbon works? Then you could easily control who could open the userform.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the subs as private and they won't show up in the Alt+F8 dialog box.

Declare them as public (the default) and they will.

Comment: I can't declare them as private because I call them from outside their own module.

Besides that, after I enter my password I want to be able to manually call them from this window.

Comment: However, it's a good solution for code that is structured differently than mine is.

Comment: You can run a private subroutine from another module with `Application.Run "modulename.subroutine"`

Comment: David Zemens: But then you'd have to make the sub containing that code public in order for it to be seen in the AltF8 dialog box, which sort of defeats the purpose.  At least as I understand the purpose.  @ilarson007: if this is only used during debugging, why not run the needed routines from within the IDE instead of via AltF8?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong approach to this and it would be better to structure your code more properly.

> The first two on that sheet are called from other macros that are run with buttons on my main worksheet.

OK. So attach these to a form control/button, and use Bigtree's suggestion to include an optional argument in these subs. They will not display in the Macros menu.  **YOU** can run them at least three different ways:

- either from the VBE by finding the procedure and pressing F5, or
- by entering the name of the procedure in the Immediate window in the VBE, or
- by pressing the buttons you have provided.

> The middle two are called when the sheet opens and closes

Sounds like this should be a private subroutine (or, use the method above from Bigtree) and CALL these from the one or more of the appropriate event handlers (at the worksheet level perhaps: `Worksheet_Activate`, `Worksheet_Deactivate`; or at the workbook level `SheetActivate` and `SheetDeactivate` depending on your needs)

You can always run the procedure manually from the Immediate window in VBE, or by manually invoking the event procedure, etc.

> and the last two I manually call when I want to edit my main sheet

Again, call from the Immediate window or manually from the VBE. You only have 6 subroutines here, it can't be that difficult to locate the ones you frequently need. Put them in a new module and organize your modules so you know where these are.

Alternatively, put some boolean in the subroutine like:

```
Sub SheetLock()

If Not Environ("username") = "YOUR_USERNAME" Then Exit Sub

'other code to do stuff is below...

End Sub
```

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

The Immediate Window is like a console/command line, it is where the result of your `Debug.Print` statements would appear, etc.  It is very handy for debugging and evaluating expressions.

[image]

There are several ways you could invoke the subroutine depending on whether it is public/private, including

- `Application.Run "MacroName"` or simply `MacroName` if public
- `Application.Run "ModuleName.MacroName"` or `Call ModuleName.MacroName` if private

Comment: Okay.  I am going to try and read this a few times to really understand what you are saying, but as for now, a few comments:

Comment: 1)  I have more than 6 subroutines; many are already made private if possible (without having known about the calling a private from another module). 2)  What do you mean by "You can always run the procedure manually from the Immediate window in VBE, or by manually invoking the event procedure, etc."

Comment: I'm going to link you to my project.  What is relevant are the subroutines options enable/disable, and sheet lock/unlock.  I would prefer that I alone can run these manually from the view macro window.  sheetlock and sheetunlock are only run manually, but I call optionsenable when i close my workbook, and I can't figure out how to call optionsdisable when I open my workbook other than activating a sheet and having it call the sub.  However, on my optionsenable/disable, I want to be able to run them manually, but not my users (this is only used when debugging essentially).

Comment: Immediate window is displayed in VBE with Ctrl + G.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vba to edit the vba code of another module.

[Is it possible in Excel VBA to change the source code of Module in another Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811343/is-it-possible-in-excel-vba-to-change-the-source-code-of-module-in-another-modul)

You can change one line or search through the lines and comment/uncomment whole blocks of code. Capturing the event when vba is unlocked may be the hard part. You may have to run a sub that does this after unlocking vba.

Comment: Although I just added this, I like what David is saying. I personally would avoid editing code with code if possible.

Comment: "You may have to run a sub that does this after unlocking vba."  Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't seen an event that's triggered when unlocking vba. You may have to manually run something to make your sub's show up in the macros dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to use a private sub,
I used the shape name to determine if from a button

On Error GoTo noshapeselected
   shapeis = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name

' I manually set the shape name in the page layout tab  selection pane
 ' below I test for the desired button
    If shapeis = "your button name" then
       goto oktogo
    else
       goto noshapeselected
    endif

noshapeselected:
       msgbox ("must run from a button")
       goto theendsub

oktogo:  'continue if desired shape was selected

theendsub:  'a button was not pushed

For those macros without buttons, but called by another macro,
set a variable to 'OK' to run a macro, then the called macro tests for 'OK'  ('OK' means initiated by another macro 'NOK' means not initiated by another macro)