# Update VBAs in multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

END GAME: A user saved Workbook opens and mirrors code from a target file.

I am trying to create a simple VBA application that has an Excel front-end and an Access back-end. There will be multiple users who would have the option to save the front-end Excel piece anywhere they desire.

I would like to know the most efficient way to be able to update macros in all user instances when I need to push updates.

Essentially, I would like to mirror code from a "global" file on `Workbook_open`. In the past I did actually set code to open a separate workbook and run code (`dim x as workbook`, `open`, `app.runmacro` and etc.), But I think that is not really the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Does the code in the Workbook have to run from Excel?  What does the Excel code do?

Comment: The excel code is transactional with the access database. Uses DAO objects to pull data and also allows user to edit access records. It has public variables, private sub-routines, and also some formatting stuff on double click, activate, updatepivot events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four possible solutions pop to mind for this (other than your option of having an intermediary workbook), there are likely others:

1. Treat the Workbook as purely an interface, and move the code to the
   Access database and have it accept the Workbook as a parameter if
   needed.  The advantage would be the code could be maintained in one
   place (Access), but it would have two main disadvantages. Each user
   would need to have Access installed in order for it to instantiate
   the application to call methods on, and it would lock in your
   "interface" - that is, changes to how it calls Access macros would
   still require Workbook updates.
2. Create a canonical Workbook and have the user Workbook version check
   against the canonical Workbook when opened.  If the version is
   different, open the new one, move all of the data to it, delete the
   old one, and save the new copy to the same filename as the old one. 
   The main disadvantage of this method would be ensuring that old code doesn't run might be difficult, as you would need
   to take measures to prevent situations where the user could abort
   the update process and still have a working copy of the old code.
3. Automate the VBE (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14822401/4088852) for implementation details -
   there are numerous resources on how to do this). Depending on how
   you wanted to do this, you could either store the current modules as
   files and import them, or store the code in the database itself and
   query for it.  The main disadvantages of this method are that the
   VBE can be fickle about changing code that is actually running. I'm
   not sure that I'd trust it to change it's own implementation.  You
   would also need to allow access to the VBE in each user's security
   settings, which may pose a security threat.
4. Store the location of the Workbooks themselves in the database, then
   push out updated copies with external code. The Workbook would
   report it's filepath when opened, and if it wasn't already recorded
   in the database, check to see if it was the most current version,
   and then write a record for itself. This has the disadvantage of
   only being able to inform the user that they don't have the current
   version if they (for example) move the Workbook in Explorer and
   don't open it until after your push.

Note that these are all "pull" type as opposed to "push" type solutions with the exception of the last one.  Regardless of the method you use for version checking, **any** push solution is going to share the disadvantage of number 4 - there is no reliable way to make sure that a push catches all the invalidated versions.

Comment: Awesome and timely feedback. I have some thinking to do on this one....As a novice coder who picked up a "side project" to get away from a giant shared spreadsheet I may be wandering dangerously close to creating another full time job for myself :) Cheers.